# Modifying apalike3 to print DOI with \href

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran, apa-style, doi, href

I am trying to modify apalike3.bst (see [here](http://journal.sjdm.org/apalike3.bst)) so that instead of printing the DOI number as a URL with hyperlink, it prints the actual DOI number but retains the hyperlink. The original DOI function is:

```
FUNCTION {format.doi} % doi
{
  doi empty$
    { "" }
    { "\url{https://doi.org/" doi * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

I'm trying to use `\href` instead: I've tried some variations and I can make it print some words hyperlinked to the right webpage, but not a DOI number that changes with the article. I thought the following would work:

```
FUNCTION {format.doi} % doi
{
  doi empty$
    { "" }
    { "\href{https://doi.org/" doi * "}{DOI:" doi * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

but I get a `the literal stack is empty` error when compiling the `.bib` file. Any clue of what should be written instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may be that the string bits aren't properly concatenated. The line

```
    { "\href{https://doi.org/" doi * "}{DOI:" doi * "}" * }
```

should read

```
    { "\href{https://doi.org/" doi * "}{DOI:" * doi * "}" * }
```

The table in page 33 of the [TameTheBeast](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf) manual has more details on this.

Comment: That works perfectly!! Thanks a lot and thanks for the reference!